# Не могу загрузить файл на сервер

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, kendo

Не получается загрузить файл на серевер через форму, использую AngularJS и RESTFul NodeJS, а так же виджеты от kendo
Код на Angular:

```
saveBook: function (data, method) {
   var url = "";
   if (method.toUpperCase() === 'PUT') {
       url = constantService.SERVER_URL + 'books/' + data._id;
   } else {
       url = constantService.SERVER_URL + 'books';
   }
   return $http({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      data: data,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   });
}
```

Код на NodeJS:

```
var express     = require('express'),
router      = express.Router(),
Category    = require('../models/Category'),
multer      = require('multer'),
upload      = multer({dest: './uploads/'}).any(),
Book        = require('../models/Book');    

.post(function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(req.file);
        console.log(req.files);
        console.log(req.body.title);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    });
```

});

`console.log(req.file)` и `console.log(req.files)` выводят `undefined`

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` - в форме имеется

Контроллер bookController:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    bookService.saveBook($scope.model, method).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.booksWindow.close();
        errorService.processError(data.message, status);
        $scope.refreshBooksTable();
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        errorService.processError(data.errmsg, status);
    })
}     

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="img">Выберите обложку</label>
            <input id="img"
                   type="file"
                   kendo-upload="img"
                   name="img"
                   class="form-control"
                   ng-model="model.img"
                   style="width: 100%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как вызывается saveBook?

Comment: Контроллер bookController:                                                            $scope.save = function () {
        bookService.saveBook($scope.model, method).success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.booksWindow.close();
            errorService.processError(data.message, status);
            $scope.refreshBooksTable();
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            errorService.processError(data.errmsg, status);
        })
    }

Comment: добавьте весь необходимый код непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: как и чем заполняется _$scope.model_?

Comment: Используется виджет kendoWindow туда помещена форма, все данные отправляются на сервер только файл не загружается.

Comment: попробуйте: `headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },` вместо того что сейчас ставите

Comment: пробовал, выводит другую ошибку `[Error: Multipart: Boundary not found]` это где вывод ошибки

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

Comment: возможно решение из этого ответа поможет http://stackoverflow.com/a/25264008/2881286

Comment: Для загрузки файла тоже используется виджет kendo-upload, так что с директивами не получится

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос информацию про используемые `kendo` и пример их использования

Comment: ну там только директивы добавляются в элементы формы, кода то и нету

Comment: пример разметки формы